# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method checkArgument(Z)V in class Lcom/facebook/common/internal/Preconditions;

Tags: android, react-native

I recently upgraded my react-native app from react-native v0.61.2 to v0.64.2, I followed the migration guide and got my app working, it works 100% fine if I login as a service provider, but when I login as a client, the app immediately crashes. The difference between the two screens is that the client screen has loads of png icons.
When I open the client screen I get a fatal exception.

```
2021-06-07 12:53:38.881 7766-7904/com.{AppName} E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FrescoDecodeExecutor-1
Process: com.{AppName}, PID: 7766
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method checkArgument(Z)V in class Lcom/facebook/common/internal/Preconditions; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.facebook.common.internal.Preconditions' appears in /data/app/~~CDeqK_xh4P5FAJduOzl8IA==/com.{AppName}-_9Bm8b_wh9Am789DNU9eUw==/base.apk)
    at com.facebook.animated.gif.GifImage.create(GifImage.java:78)
    at com.facebook.animated.gif.GifImage.decode(GifImage.java:84)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedImageFactoryImpl.decodeGif(AnimatedImageFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at com.facebook.fresco.animation.factory.AnimatedFactoryV2Impl$1.decode(AnimatedFactoryV2Impl.java:89)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder.decodeGif(DefaultImageDecoder.java:139)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder$1.decode(DefaultImageDecoder.java:60)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder.decode(DefaultImageDecoder.java:120)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.internalDecode(DecodeProducer.java:386)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.doDecode(DecodeProducer.java:328)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.access$400(DecodeProducer.java:145)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder$1.run(DecodeProducer.java:198)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler.doJob(JobScheduler.java:224)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler.access$000(JobScheduler.java:24)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler$1.run(JobScheduler.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Anybody knows what's going on here?

Comment: Check this path : NoSuchMethodError: No static method checkArgument(Z)V in class Lcom/facebook/common/internal/Preconditions;

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution, it looks like I had implementations in my dependencies that I didn't need inside the app build.gradle.
I didn't have any animations so I decided to comment out the two implementations, and voila!

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.9.0'
```